# Is HAVE GOT an idiom ? And are those patterns correct?

Tags: british-english

I'm confused, is "have got" a verb? Because when I've searched it in a dictionary, it said "have got" was an equivalent of "have", the form is like the "Present Perfect Tense", and it is the equivalent of "have" in British English. I've ever heard that "have got" can't be used in every situation, and only "have" can be used in all situation and all verbs, is that right?

These are the examples. So, do you hear them in standard British English?

I have already got to go (or) I already have to go.

I never have a new pen when I need one (or) I have never got a new pen when I need one.

I have got to do it (or) I have to do it.

I have still got to research itsign those contracts (or) I still have to research itsign those contracts.

I have just/only got five pence (or) I just/only have five pence.

I have also got to do my homework (or) I also have to do my homework.

I haven't just/only  got 5 pence (or) I just/only don't have 5 pence.

Have/ haven't I just/only got 5 pence? (Or) do/don't I have 5 pence?

I have/haven't also got to do it (or) I also don't have to do it.

Have/haven't I also got to do it? (Or) do/don't I also have to do it?

So In the past, do you use "had got" or "had in BrE?
e.g.

I had got 5 pounds (or) I (did have) had 5 pounds.

I hadn't got 5 pounds (or) I did not have 5 pounds.

Had/hadn't I got 5 pounds? (Or) did/didn't I have 5 pounds?

Answer (score 0):

*Have got* is an emphasized form of *have* when used as a normal verb.  I think this is in the category of "everyone uses it but it's not really correct English" similar to the word *ain't*, for example.

It works with the normal meaning of *X has/have/had Y* in the sense that X possesses Y:

> I have 2 dollars -> I have got 2 dollars.
>
> I have a chance to survive -> You haven't got any chance to survive.

It also works with *X has/have/had to Y* in the sense that X will suffer a negative consequence if Y is not done:

> I have to go to school today.
>
> I have to talk to my boss about taking time off for the hospital.

Note that *got* is also the past-participle form of *get* in AmE (I read that it's *gotten* in BrE which you may also hear occasionally in AmE).  So it can be used in the perfect forms of *get*, as well as it's phrasal variations e.g. *get it*, *get out*, *get up*.  In this case it's just a different tense/aspect of *get*, etc.

> I'm getting 10 dollars from Michael today -> I've just got 10 dollars from Michael.
>
> I'm getting up at 3am for work -> I'd got up at 3am for work that day, when I heard a crash.
>
> I need to get out of the apartment -> I have just got out of the apartment.

A meaning of *get X* is "do or experience something to become X" or "do or experience something to make X completed, finished, or achieved".  This meaning of *get* can have perfect forms, and it looks like *have got* above, but really isn't.  I want to say you probably will hear *gotten* more likely when this meaning is intended but I don't have evidence to back that up.

> I'm getting my nails done -> She has got her nails done.
>
> I'm getting hot, can we turn down the heat? -> I had got so hot yesterday because they left the heat on.